# Increasing the number of office communicator conversations stored by outlook2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, communicator

I am sure everyone has had this, you get an email and instead of replying to it in the negative you pop open a communicator window and bang away and answer the question/ propose something else / say no.
Several days / weeks/ months later you get "why didn't you do this or that, i emailed you" you say i pinged you on communicator. you go back to "conversation History (if you have it turned on) and find that it is only recording 2 weeks worth of conversations.

Is there anyway of increasing this?

I have found plenty of info on turning it on, changing colors etc but nothing on this.

I am running office pro plus 2010
Communicator is 2007

help would be appreciated, the conversation i don't have is the one where i proposed a new time to the boss regarding my performance review. I know that one is gone, but i would like to avoid this in the future. (luckily there was another manger there a the time and he heard it. so when i didnt turn up for the meeting i didnt get into trouble..... well too much....)

Chris

Comment: I found this when I used the logical search query on this subject.  Does it do what you want?  http://mscommunicatorhistor.codeplex.com/